# How to display string in the format ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4 etc

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to display a string in the format ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4 etc in 'N' number of times. Can any one help me to solve this c# programme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you want:

```
int n = 10;
IEnumerable<String> ips =  Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(i => "ip" + i);
String allIPs = String.Join(",", ips);
```

Result:

```
ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4,ip5,ip6,ip7,ip8,ip9,ip10
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/LDZNDk)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myIps = String.Join(", ",(Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => "ip" + i)));
```

myIps will be ip1, ip2, ip3....ip10

Comment: Why are you posting my answer once more  ? ;-)